# Cosmos DB Sql Api - Query C# escaped inner json

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a situation where data is coming in but one of the properties is a JSON object but it is escaped:

```
   {
    "Evaporator_Temperature": 68,
    "Gateway_Info": "{\"temp_sensor\":0.00,\"temp_pcb\":77.00}"
    }
```

I can query Evaporator_Temperature but I can't get at temp_pcb, I am assuming because it is escaped. I cannot change the incoming data because it is coming in from a IoT device.

I have tried:

I have tried a few different angles:

```
SELECT a.temp_pcb FROM c
join a in c.Gateway_Info

SELECT c.Gateway_Info.temp_pcb FROM c

SELECT c.Gateway_Info["\"temp_pcb\""] FROM c

SELECT c.Gateway_Info["temp_pcb"] FROM c
```

What can I do to get at temp_pcb?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you check if it is saved as an escaped string to begin with?

Comment: Unfortunately it is

Comment: Do you have control over how it is saved? I know you said it's coming from an IoT device but don't you have access to it?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: The flow: device -> IotHub -> Stream Analytics -> CosmosDB

Comment: Are you mapping this response to some POCO in the C# app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170686/discussion-between-rsh-and-nick-chapsas).

Answer (score 0):

So this was solved in the chat but here is the solution.

Using `JSON.parse(input.Gateway_Info)` in the function will convert the string to a JSON object and it will let you query it.

Comment: I seriously hope the conversion to json function will be ran BEFORE data is saved to CosmosDB or otherwise the data could not be indexed and querying may require full scan for many queries.

Comment: I don't know if you have access to the chat but yes i suggested the data is replaced with object json not serialized string and then it is changed to be inserted like that to begin with.

Comment: ok, It's in the hinted chat, but missing from this answer. You could extract the important parts from chat to make the answer self-contained.